# What does 这些地方 mean in this dialogue about health checks?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm confused about the use of 这些地方 in the following dialogue in my Chinese text book (click for larger image):

[image: Chinese dialogue]

I'll transcribe it below:

> 马克：[体检](http://dict.cn/%E4%BD%93%E6%A3%80)时[检查](http://dict.cn/%E6%A3%80%E6%9F%A5)什么？
>   丁波：很多。[耳朵](http://dict.cn/%E8%80%B3%E6%9C%B5)，[眼睛](http://dict.cn/%E7%9C%BC%E7%9D%9B)，[鼻子](http://dict.cn/%E9%BC%BB%E5%AD%90)，[牙齿](http://dict.cn/%E7%89%99%E9%BD%BF)，还有[胃](http://dict.cn/%E8%83%83)等等。
>   马克：以前我总是[肚子](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%9A%E5%AD%90)[疼](http://dict.cn/%E7%96%BC)。
>   丁波：可能是胃疼吧。你去[医院](http://dict.cn/%E5%8C%BB%E9%99%A2)检查一下儿吧。
>   马克：体检时[胳膊](http://dict.cn/%E8%83%B3%E8%86%8A)，[手](http://dict.cn/%E6%89%8B)，[脚](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%9A)要不要检查？
>   丁波：这些[地方](http://dict.cn/%E5%9C%B0%E6%96%B9)一般没有大问题，看一看就行了。

And here's my translation:

> Mark: When you get a health check, what is checked?
>   Ding Bo: Lots. Ears, eyes, nose, teeth, also stomach, and so on.
>   Mark: In the past, my tummy has been always painful.
>   Ding Bo: It could be your stomach that's painful.  You go to the hospital for a check [suggestive particle].
>   Mark: When you get a health check, are arms, hands, feet inspected?
>   Ding Bo: These places generally have no big problems, have a look and it'll be okay.

In particular, I'm unclear if "these places" (这些地方) means the places you go to get 体检 (health checks), or if "these places" means these places on your body (胳膊，手，脚).

**Question**: What does 这些地方 mean in this dialogue about health checks?

Comment: "这些地方" refers to "胳膊，手，脚" mentioned in the Mark's question.

Comment: '这些地方' means 'these areas'

Comment: health talk：我这个  **地方**  有点疼

Comment: You are very courteous to link many words to the dictionary!

Comment: @songyuanyao That is an answer. Maybe you could spend a few minutes writing it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[指示代词](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8C%87%E7%A4%BA%E4%BB%A3%E8%AF%8D/19411158#viewPageContent) (demonstrative pronoun) (like "这些") is usually used in place of things mentioned in the context, to make the sentence terse and economical.

So "这些地方" refers to "胳膊，手，脚" mentioned in Mark's question, the sentence is equivalent as:

```
马克：体检时胳膊、手、脚要不要检查？
丁波：胳膊、手、脚一般没有大问题，看一看就行了。
```

Answer (score 2):

In this context, '这些地方'(these places) refers to '**areas**' on a human body.

For example:

'upper arm area' (上臂一带)

'left wrist and left lower palm area' (左腕及左掌底部一带)

'neck and spine area '(颈椎一带)

Answer (score 1):

Putting 这些地方 in this setting is not that good technically. It's okay in spoken.

这些部位 is more technical for 'body parts'. So, 这些部位一般没有大问题...